# Obj-C applicationWillResignActive - distinguish between events

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

Is there a way to detect what kind of event triggered
`-(void)applicationWillResignActive` in Objective-C?

Now, the method is called for all kind of events, including:

**incoming calls, showing of notification or control center, closing the app.**

I need to distinguish between closing the app and showing of notification or control center, so the app does not execute certain logic only when the notification or control center is shown, as the app will still stay visible in the background.

I need to clear cache, cookies and disconnect from API when the app closes or another app is opened, as the app will display sensitive information.

Answer (score 3):

I just published a little UIWindow subclass that does exactly that. You simply subscribe to an NSNotification and can react to the user opening Control Center. Detailed instructions and setup on Github: [AAWindow](https://github.com/aaronabentheuer/AAWindow).

The detection of Control Center is actually quite simple. Just take a look at `AAWindow.swift`. This can be easily recreated for Notification Center, but only if your app is in "full-screen"-mode (no UIStatusbar).

Answer (score 2):

When you close the app the method applicationDidEnterBackground is being called in addition to applicationWillResignActive

Comment: OK, I guess I can do stuff like disconnecting from API and clearing cache and cookies in applicationDidEnterBackground. But where should I redraw the interface and show a login dialog, which is needed for the case that the app closes and is opened again?

Comment: You can make modifications to your UI in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. The screenshot shown in the apps list when you double-tap on the home button is taken right after you return from this method, so you should make sure to hide any sensitive information from your UI before you return from that method. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: You can do it in: applicationWillEnterForeground